# spacy- custom tokenization doesn't work with POS and ORTH and OP argument

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I'm trying to implement custom tokenization to separate
words like
'6-inch-long','6-feet','3-meter-tall'

So i set the custom tokenizer as below.

```
from spacy.symbols import ORTH,POS

# Add special case rule
special_case = [{'pos': "NUM"}, {'F': "-"}, {'pos': "NOUN"},{'F': "-",'op':'?'},{'pos': "ADJ",'op':'?'}]
# special_case = [{POS: "NUM"}, {ORTH: "-"}, {POS: "NOUN"},{ORTH: "-"},{POS: "ADJ"}]
nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case("dashed", special_case)

# Check new tokenization
print([w.text for w in nlp("6-inch-long")])  # ['gim', 'me', 'that']
```

It returns error message saying

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-987-f37f530be1e3> in <module>
      6 special_case = [{'pos': "NUM"}, {'F': "-"}, {'pos': "NOUN"},{'F': "-",'op':'?'},{'pos': "ADJ",'op':'?'}]
      7 # special_case = [{POS: "NUM"}, {ORTH: "-"}, {POS: "NOUN"},{ORTH: "-"},{POS: "ADJ"}]
----> 8 nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case("dashed", special_case)
      9 
     10 # Check new tokenization

tokenizer.pyx in spacy.tokenizer.Tokenizer.add_special_case()

vocab.pyx in spacy.vocab.Vocab.make_fused_token()

KeyError: 65
```

And I googled about this and somebody says it would be resolved if I replace
ORTH=> 'F', POS=>'pos' but it still doesn't work out and also I couldn't find
the way to put 'optional' parameter for custom tokenization.
The reason why I need optional tokenization parameter is
that i need to tokenize both '6-inch-long' and '6-feet'.
which means the fourth and fifth elements have to stay as 'optional'.

How do I solve this?

Thank you always.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've misunderstood the `tokenizer.add_special_case` API. The first argument is the **token string** that you would like to tokenize in a particular way and the second argument is how to tokenize that particular token string only. It looks similar, but it's not a `Matcher` pattern.

```py
nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case("dashed", [{"ORTH": "dash"}, {"ORTH": "ed"}])
```

If you want to do something more complicated that involves matching tokens based on annotation like `POS`, you can use the `Matcher` and the retokenizer (https://spacy.io/api/doc#retokenize) to modify the tokenization.

There are also some differences between spaCy v2 and v3 to be aware of:

- v2 doesn't validate that the `ORTH` strings add up to the token string, which means you can (accidentally) modify the input text
- v2 lets you set attributes beyond `ORTH` and `NORM`
- v2 doesn't support whitespace in the token string

Comment: Thank you! I looked into retokenizer but it seems like I have to provide what the ending result is going to be like ['New','York'] which means it's not generalize the pattern. How do I make a pattern for splitting all the words having hyphen in the middle or several times within the token?

Comment: If all you want to do is split on hyphens, modify the tokenizer infixes.